# How to batch rename files in Linux and swapping the first word in the filename with the second?

Tags: file, rename

I have multiple .jpg files like:

```
John-Smith-Aug-24-2000.jpg    
Robert-Detrie-Mon-Mar-19-1934.jpg
John-Lane-Mon-Oct-2-1967.jpg
```

I'm not sure how to just swap the first and second names/words around and leave the rest as is.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename` command for this. It lets you run an arbitrary bit of Perl, such a regex replacement, on all files:

```
rename 's/^([^-]*)-([^-]*)/$2-$1/' *.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting how this works on a Debian system, but does nothing on an older CentOS system.  I wonder why that is?

Comment: @brovary3154 You may need to use `prename` instead on the older CentOS system.